# starlette doesn't appear to run requests concurrently

Tags: python, locust, uvicorn, starlette

I am using a simple demo Starlette app (right out of the docs, just added an `asyncio.sleep()` statement there:

```
import asyncio
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
from starlette.routing import Route


async def homepage(request):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return JSONResponse({'hello': 'world'})


app = Starlette(debug=True, routes=[
    Route('/', homepage),
])
```

I am running this using `uvicorn`

Using a load testing client (e.g. locust, or a custom test client), I see that I get 1 response per second, which implies no parallelism.

Shouldn't Starlette serve multiple requests concurrently?

Comment: Please show the `uvicorn` command you used to start the app and also the command you used for load-testing. Thank you.

Comment: have just tried and the above works fine for me, more details are needed to be able reproduce your issue